# Selecting several cross section on a specific distance using expression

Tags: qgis-3, expression, select-by-attribute

I have the following river cross section lines. I want to select cross sections which is multiple of 10 from the attribute 'TR_SEGMENT' (Eg: 1,10,20,30...etc) or any "nth" sections. What is the SQL expression for this process?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open "Select By Expression" window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), enter te following expression:

```
TR_SEGMENT % 10 = 0 or TR_SEGMENT = 1
```

You need `TR_SEGMENT = 1` because 1 is not multiple of 10. Using `TR_SEGMENT % 10 = 0` selects also the feature which has 0 value of `TR_SEGMENT` if it exists.

PS: `%` is the modulo operator, which returns the remainder of dividing two numbers. In this case, `TR_SEGMENT` is multiple of 10 if the remainder is `0`.

[image]

Comment: it works thanks, I do not need the TR segment=1. Can you explain me briefly what does this %=0 function ?

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator, which returns the remainder of dividing two numbers.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a bit lame but working approach using the following expression:

```
array_contains(array_insert(generate_series(10, 100, 10), 0, 1), "id")
```

It includes the following functions:
[`generate_series()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#generate-series), [`array_insert()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-insert), and [`array_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-contains).

`generate_series(10, 100, 10)` produces an array `[ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ]`

`array_insert(generate_series(10, 100, 10), 0, 1)` results in `[ 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ]`

Comment: Probably will be helpful to me in another time